# How to configure function in SQLite with dbo. prefix

Tags: python, sqlite, sybase

Using Sybase as the main transactional DB and SQLite as the in memory DB for Integration tests.
Issue I am facing is conflicting behavior of the two implementations.

I need to execute a query similar to

```
select dbo.get_name(id), id from some_table
```

This runs perfectly fine in sybase (I understand the importance of schema prefix for user defined functions). However SQL lite throws error saying SQLite.Operational error near "("

Tried to add dbo as schema while creating SQLite connections but no luck.

Using Python for all the implementation.

Comment: Use a sysbase database for your testing too.

Answer (score 0):

You could make dbo a group, and make all your users member of that group. Then you could avoid using the schema prefix at all.

Or, you could have a SQLite database named dbo where you put the function `get_name`.